# Flutter Collection Name

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]
is there is any way we can find out subcollection names present inside a document

```
Future<List<String>> fetchSubcollectionNames(String documentPath) async {
    List<String> subcollectionNames = [];

    DocumentReference documentRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('DailyProjectReport').doc(documentPath);

    CollectionReference subcollectionRef = documentRef.collection('');

    QuerySnapshot subcollectionSnapshot = await subcollectionRef.get();

    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot subDocSnapshot in subcollectionSnapshot.docs) {

      subcollectionNames.add(subDocSnapshot.id);
    }
    // Return the list of subcollection names
    print(subcollectionNames);
    return subcollectionNames;
  }
```

I have tried this code but still not able to find out subcollection names in flutter.

Comment: Web and mobile clients can't do this. If your data is structured in such a way that requires the app to list subcollections, then your data modeling is not compatible with the way Firestore wants you to do things. Documents and collections are not like files and folders in a filesystem. Collections are meant to be groups of related data that are pre-defined to have a meaning. Collections names should not be dynamic - the model should define ahead of time what each collection is and what it means.